# Crossfilter - how to find min/max

Tags: crossfilter

I am probably missing something trivial. I guess I still do not fully understand some basic crossfilter concepts

Anyway, I created a crossfilter with a few dimensions with filters on the dimensions. I now want to know the min/max of the filtered values (not the keys).

How would I achieve this?

All tips welcomed.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1):

If you are using d3.js, you can use the "extent" method.  I am just starting to play around with Cross filter to do some charting and here is a snippet that I have been using.

```
var strmDateAccessor = function (d){return d.strmDate;};
strmDateExtent = [];
strmDateExtent = d3.extent(data, strmDateAccessor);

// strmDateExtent[0] will equal min
// strmDateExtent[1] will equal max
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, but the goal was to get a filtered crossfilter dimensions min/max values. The background of this question can be found in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/oMbflgz-ywY. The "solution" I came up with is also in there, although the hack can hardly be called solution.